# Why does sh step on second node in Jenkins pipeline fail?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Trying to execute a `sh` step on a second `node()` is failing.
Minimal example:

```groovy
node('windows') {
    env.PATH = "C:\\some\\path;${env.PATH}"
    // ...
}

node('linux') {
    sh "echo 'Hello World!'" // this fails
}
```

The error message is:

```
nohup: failed to run command 'sh': No such file or directory
```

The `PATH` environment variable is set correctly to contain the `sh` command on both nodes.

Why does the `sh` step on the second node fail?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986628/setting-a-per-node-environment-variable-in-a-pipeline-job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The problem was setting `env.PATH` with an assignment. Use [`withEnv()`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) instead:

```groovy
node('windows') {
    withEnv('PATH+some=C:\\some\\path') {
        // ...
    }
}

node('linux') {
    sh "echo 'Hello World!'"
}
```

#### Explanation:

In one of the later sections of the [pipeline tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multiple-threads), it is said that

> environment variable overrides are limited to being global to a pipeline run

This means that when setting an environment variable like this `env.PATH = ...` this variable is **fixed for the rest of the pipeline script** and will therefore **overwrite the actual value of that environment variable on all following nodes**. So it reverses the normal behavior where the `env` properties are set to the actual value of the environment variables of the node.

So our Linux node ended up with the `PATH` variable of the Windows node.
That's why `sh` wasn't found.
*Note for the curious:* `nohup` was still found because it is executed directly by the Jenkins client which uses the "real" environment variables of the node. But Jenkins then sets the modified environment for the `nohup` process which is why `nohup` could not find `sh` in the `PATH`.

Comment: I had withEnv("PATH=something:$env.PATH") which is also bad for cross-platform compatibility.  PATH+X=  is the way to go.